# Quick to comment, but never a reply

Tags: discussion, comments

Why do people comment, with a derogatory statement, almost immediately, but then fail to reply or interact with me, the author, thus degrading the question entirely?

Why do that to someone else? I have a strong feeling that the same person also down-voted. That makes me so angry.
I never expected an instant downvote and comment. When someone comments I expect an answer back when I reply.

*[Virtual Photon Laser](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644735/)*

Comment: Were you expecting folks to respond immediately on demand? Many people have work to do, and check up on SE in bits of spare time. Any supposition of who downvoted should be suppressed - you are projecting anger on to somebody who may not actually have downvoted.

Comment: Per the edit "*When someone comments I expect an answer back when I reply*", please read my answer. Users often will not reply right away to you, nor do they even have to reply at all.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the comments were removed, so I can't say anything about this particular situation (which is probably a good thing). Some general points.

1. Questions stand on their own. Comments on questions don't degrade the questions then themselves.
2. If you think a user is making derogatory comments, please flag them for a moderator to review and continue on with your day.
3. This is not an instant messaging/social media site. Users are not expected to reply instantly to comments, nor are they expected to reply at all. Of course it's not fun for someone to comment something and then "ghost" you, but that happens here sometimes. However, given that your post is only a few hours old, you should definitely give it some more time before you give your judgement in the way you have; it is pretty common for people to leave comments, go live their lives, and then come back to the site many hours later.